# Xcode project run in one device but not in another

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm testing my Xcode project in simulator and in 2 iPhones 6. Both iPhones are identical and actually bought together on the same time. That was couple of years ago. Now Phone #1 is running on iOS 9.3.2 and Phone #2 is running on 9.3.1. I have Xcode pros with deployment target of 9.3. Xcode version is 7.3

I can run my Xcode project in the simulator fine and when I plugged phone #2, but on #1, it will execute fewer lines than #2 and then stops.

I have went though all the paths in this [article](http://blog.neverthesamecolor.net/how-to-recover-disk-space-from-xcode/) and deleted all of these one at time:

- ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
- ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/
- ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/
- ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
- ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

I have also tried restarted the Xcode in every of the steps above, and restarting my iPhone then plugging it when it loads. Nothing worked

Like I said the code for phone #1 actually runs a little bit, but then stops executing further lines. I stepped through code to see why and where my phone #1. There was no error, the execution just stops, sometimes at the same place, sometimes a little earlier.
Phone #2 runs all code just fine and returns results.

What's going on!? Why does it work in one iPhone but not in the other, even though both are running the same phone and same version!? Is there another cache path that I should try to also delete!?

**UPDATE #1:**
per @daneejela questions:
The line where it stops is different each time. When I setup the provision profile happened a while ago. Phone#1 was if not the only phone, was the first one I would test my provision setup or not. It was only couple of weeks ago where it stopped working on phone#1.

**UPDATE #2:**
somehow my profile in apple developer got all messed up and was showing invalid. I had to regenerate it and it worked right away.

Comment: 1.) Does it stop working on the same line each time (on phone #1)?   
2.) Do you have maybe on phone #1 installed app previously with the other provisioning profile or your provisioning profile maybe doesn't include your phone #1 udid?

Comment: thx. check my update#1 that I just did.

Comment: When you say "then stops executing further lines", do you mean you receive a crash ? Have you evaluated crash log then ? Have you checked device console for Phone#1 ? Also, could you please check if it enters in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` callback in any of your controller ?

Comment: didn't think of those. I'll follow them next time. Issue is fixed after creating a new profile.

Comment: it happened again to me today. I tried doing 2 things at the same time and then it worked:
1. I  haven't tried installing in phone #2, so I did
2. cleared lots of space in my iPhone 
I think that #2 is what made it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen strange behavior with apple developer importing/exporting. One thing that is worth trying is, if feasible, to regenerate your provision profile at the apple developer if you are still at the developer phase. If that makes it work, try not to touch those settings again or perform any operations against them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already checked device setting: wifi, airplaneMode....
Then try to delete app from both device and retry first on iPhone#2. (may be you have saved a different value in a userDefault during previous testing kind of staff that remains in device.. that you are using in your request).
Also try with another user or new user (your server may have association between device-user). 
also show your `request` detail and explain how your server handle users

Comment: I updated the post by removing that misleading note of Post to server. I just tested it again and it happens much earlier than that, so it is not related to the server. sorry about that. btw: I am not using userDefault. Also, I was able to bring up app in iPhone #1 all the time until recently.

Comment: did you deleted the app completely from device before testing

Comment: yes yes... all the time actually before every test.

Comment: do you get message of losing connection to device.. maybe its related to usb-cable or device input

Comment: no no messages of any kind neither at Xcode nor phone. I wish it was showing me any error. The execution goes and goes and then silence!

Comment: even though I am using the same usb cable with the working phone (#2)?

Comment: Yeah, there is no other reasons ...when you get that situation try to adjust cable  Xcode may show connection lost error or otherwise will continue...

Comment: Yeah I tried another cable... same behavior.  If I don't get an answer I will try to update Xcode and my phone to latest. I don't want to endanger working state of phone #2